# Find the first occurrence of matching regex after the first occurrence of another regex has been found

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

My file looks like this

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com
  #Username username2
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username2

Host github-username1
  #Username username1
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_username1
```

I'd like to find the first username after `github.com` so it would return in this case, `username2`.

Answer (score 1):

To grab first *Username* after *Host github.com*:

```
$ awk '/Host github.com/ {f=1; next} f==1&& /Username/ {f=0; print $2}' file
username2
```

Comment: @DanielKobe It prints the output you requested, no other extraneous lines.

Comment: how do I pipe the output to a file, when I do `awk 'the command here' file > newfile.txt` it adds nothing to the newfile`

Comment: @DanielKobe You don't pipe anything to a file, you redirect. If you want to _add_ to a file as in append you use `>>`. Other than that, you need to restate your question.

Comment: @JamesBrown yes sorry, I meant the redirection doesn't work, it doesn't create a new file

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'f&&/Username/{print $2; exit} /github\.com/{f=1}' file
```